# Making indoor navigation by using regular Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, indoor

If i have indoor data such as (details, levels, points of interest) but I don't have the Indoors extension.

Can I navigate between ground floor and first floor by using regular network analyst extension (find best route) for example?

Comment: You can model any cost network as you like, but it would probably be easier to use the tool engineered for the task.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap when you try to do this?

Comment: ArcGIS pro @PolyGeo

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.